# ошибки 1004 и 424 когда задаёшь .Interior.ColorIndex

Tags: excel, vba

пытаюсь написать пару функций для Excel 2010 в VBA
но постоянно вылетает ошибка

```
Pablic Function SetClrIndex(rng As Range, ColorIndex As Integer)
    rng.Cells(1,1).Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex ' тут "Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error"
End Function
```

если перед `rng.Cells(1,1).Interior.` поставить `set` тогда ошибка "Error 424: Object required"

в функцию передаётся диапазон заданный пользователем

подскажите как справиться с данной проблемой?

Comment: 1) P**u**blic, а не P**a**blic; 2) Sub, а не Function.

Comment: исправил, но ошибки так и остались (((((

Comment: Функция возвращает значение, В же пытаетесь изменить цвет другой ячейки. Что Вы хотите получить? Опишите ЗАДАЧУ.

Comment: Оба исправления внесены? ошибки ТЕ ЖЕ ?

Comment: 1. на сколько я понимаю функция cells берёт данные из переданного ей диапазона, т.е. из rgn, мне надо в этом диапазоне изменить цвет первой слева сверху ячейки

2. да, Pablic на Public изменил, а ошибки те же (((

Comment: дополнение: вот тут https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells в первом примере написано что передаётся диапазон B2:Z100 и cells работает именно с ним

Comment: UDF (функции пользователя) не предназначены для изменения значений других ячеек, они, как и формулы листа, возвращают значение в ячейку, из которой вызваны. Уточните, почему именно функции? Ваша UDF записана в ячейке или работает без размещения на листе? По какому событию должна производиться заливка указанного диапазона?

Comment: А не могли-бы вы еще дописать как вы собственно процедуру вызываете? Тоесть имеется ввиду что-то типа `SetClrIndex [A1:B5], 5`

Comment: @vikttur - жаль

Comment: @Andrey функция вызова, установленная в ячейке: `Public Function IsValue(cell as Range) as Integer`  `If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then`  `SetClrIndex cell, xlColorIndexAutomatic`  `IsValue=1`  `End If`  `End Function`

Comment: @woojin. к сожалению воспроизвести Вашу ошибку не удалось. У меня Ваш код работает. Может быть опишете задачу в целом? Вероятно так будет проще определить места возможного возникновения ошибки (она может быть не в этой процедуре/функции).

Comment: всем спасибо! мне уже подсказали на другой стороне форума (на английской), что пользовательская функция (UDF) не может изменять цвет ячейки даже косвенно

Comment: *мне уже подсказали на другой стороне форума* - а я Вам о чем писал?!

Comment: вы писали об изменении "другой" ячейки которая не относится к диапазону, а не о том что UDF не может менять цвет какой либо ячейки

Comment: Не, я писал об изменении ЛЮБОЙ ДРУГОЙ ячейки (не той, в которой записана функция)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень важное замечание: если не хотите дополнительной головной боли, никогда не называйте переменные, функции, процедуры зарезервированными именами (`IsValue, ColorIndex`...).

*UDF* (функции пользователя) не предназначены для изменения других ячеек, они, как и формулы листа, возвращают значение в ячейку, из которой вызваны. В данном случае применение *UDF* ошибочно. Но задача решаема.

В модуль листа пишем процедуру реагирования на событие листа - изменение значения в диапазоне:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim lColor_ As Long

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A2:A50"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        If Not IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then
            Set rRng = Range("C2:D15")
            lColor_ = 48
            Call SetClrIndex(rRng, lColor_)
        End If

        Set rRng = Nothing
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

В общем модуле:

```
Sub SetClrIndex(rRng As Range, lColor_ As Long)
    rRng.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = lColor_
End Sub
```

При изменении ячейки в диапазоне `A2:A50` (только при записи значения - `If Not IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then`) передается управление макросу, который отвечает за заливку ячейки указанного диапазона.

Назначение объекта переменной (`Set rRng`) и указание цвета (`lColor_`) в событийной процедуре неоправдано. Это лишь для примера. Данные можно брать из ячеек, задавать условием, вычислять в поцедуре заливки...

Comment: ооо! спасибо! это интересный вариант